# how to remove item checked

Tags: android, user-interface, checkbox, baseadapter

I have my Box adapter that extends BaseAdapter

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  Context ctx;
  LayoutInflater lInflater;
  ArrayList<Product> objects;
  CheckBox cbBuy;

  BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }   
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
          view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.childitem, parent, false);
        }

    Product p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

    cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

    cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);

    cbBuy.setTag(position);

    cbBuy.setChecked(p.box);
    return view;
  }

  Product getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Product) getItem(position));
  }

  ArrayList<Product> getBox() {
    ArrayList<Product> box = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product p : objects) {
      // если в корзине
      if (p.box)
        box.add(p);
    }
    return box;
  }

  OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

      getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
    }
  };
}
```

now in the MainActivity I have to find out what checkbox was checked and remove it.

How can I do it. What method to invoke to getItemId position and how. Thank you in advance.

```
case R.id.delete:

 if (boxAdapter.cbBuy.isChecked()) {

   products.remove( checked position id );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create method `getBoxProducts` in your adapter:

```
    public void removeBoxProducts()
    {
        List<Product> trash = new ArrayList<Product>();
        for (Product product:objects)
        {
            if (product.box)
            {
                trash.add(product);
            }
        }
        for (Product product:trash)
        {
            objects.remove(product);
        }
    }
```

To access this method use following:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewByIf(R.id.list_view_id);
BoxAdapter adapter = (BoxAdapter)list.getAdapter();
adapter.removeBoxProducts();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I thought that in my adapter there is a method to find checked item id and delete it. Like public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
      } But I stack with calling it. I am a new one.

Comment: Are you extending your activity from `ListActivity`?

Comment: public class ChildActivity extends Activity {

Comment: ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    BoxAdapter boxAdapter;

Comment: Can I just invoke existing methods to find checkedbox id and then to remove it? Like products.remove(boxAdapter.getItemId(how to find checkbox checked?));

Comment: I have found my mistake. Thank you for code providing and sorry for bothering.